# Connecting to oracle in same way SQL+ uses

Tags: c#, oracle

I regularly run the same SQL command against multiple different oracle databases we have. I am trying to create a simple C# program that will allow me to run the command and display the data in a DataGrid. I am not the DBA of the database and currently have access to to the DB's using SQL+. Is there a way I can connect to the database, run a statement and disconnect so that it runs a the database end in exactly the same way as if I had used SQL plus?

I have seen different methods of connecting to oracle from C# but my question is mainly aimed to find out which one would work in my current setup, where SQL+ works.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet as I don't want to get in trouble for using the wrong method. I was just wondering which would appear the same at the server side as SQL+. I have read about ODP.NET, OleDB, basic connection strings, TNS etc..

Comment: Since the server sees the name of the process for example your connection even when using the same technical protocol would be identifiable... How exact must be the "same appearance" on the server-side in your case ?

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be identical. I am not trying to hide what I am doing or anything, it's more to avoid having to get special permissions etc raised and to ensure I don't cause any problems with the DB servers.

Comment: Basically SQL Plus works with TNS and uses OCI which is the native Oracle interface... I use "Devart dotconnect for Oracle" which a commercial ADO.NET provider... there is also ODP.NET (free, provided by Oracle)...

Comment: why not keep using sql*plus? what's wrong with it? )

Answer (score 0):

It won't matter in which way you connect to the database. The privileges are connected to your username the Oracle database. SQL+ is just a tool you use to connect to the database.

So if you're able to connect to the database in code with your username you can issue the query the same way you would in SQL+.